# JPasswordField on top of Image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jlabel

I have this code that creates a Jframe where I add a JLabel with a picture and a JpasswordField. I want the JpasswordField to be on top of the image but only depending on where I do the `f.add` I get one of them showed or not... I want the JpasswordField to be on top of the picture to allow the user to introduce a password but with the picture as background.

Here is the code:

```
package java;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

public class Java implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Java());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        /*Keep on front*/
        f.toFront();
        f.repaint();
        f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        f.setExtendedState( f.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setUndecorated(true);

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        f.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width-5, screenSize.height-100);
        double width = screenSize.getWidth();
        double height = screenSize.getHeight();

        System.out.println(width+"   "+height);


        BufferedImage myPicture = null;
        try {
            myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\image.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Image dimg = myPicture.getScaledInstance((int)width, (int)height,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dimg));

        JPasswordField myTextfield = new JPasswordField("Password");
        myTextfield.setEchoChar('*'); // U+26AB

        picLabel.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
        picLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.BOTTOM);

        /*Depending of who I add first the image or the JPasswordField is showed*/
        f.add(myTextfield);
        f.add(picLabel);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your code should be geared towards creating JPanels, and you should control the layout manager of this JPanel directly. Then you can place and display your JPanel in a JDialog **not** a JFrame, since much of your code appears to be trying to emulate a dialog's actions (such as keeping it on top and such).

That being sad, one of your big problems is that you're ignoring the layout manager that the JFrame's contentPane is using, the BorderLayout. By adding components to it in a default fashion, you will cover up anything that was added to the same position previously. Instead I suggest:

- Create a JPanel
- Draw your image as a background image in the JPanel's `paintComponent` methd.
- Add your JLabel to your JPanel.
- Display the JPanel in a JDialog not a JFrame.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogExample extends JPanel {
   private static final int COLUMN_COUNT = 10;
   private static final int I_GAP = 3;
   public static final String BKG_IMG_PATH = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/"
         + "thumb/9/92/Camels_in_Jordan_valley_%284568207363%29.jpg/800px-Camels_in_Jordan_valley_"
         + "%284568207363%29.jpg";

   private BufferedImage backgrndImage;
   private JTextField userNameField = new JTextField();
   private JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
   private JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
   private JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

   public DialogExample(BufferedImage backgrndImage) {
      this.backgrndImage = backgrndImage;
      userNameField.setColumns(COLUMN_COUNT);
      passwordField.setColumns(COLUMN_COUNT);

      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
      btnPanel.setOpaque(false);
      btnPanel.add(okButton);
      btnPanel.add(cancelButton);

      GridBagConstraints gbc = getGbc(0, 0, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
      mainPanel.add(createLabel("User Name", Color.white), gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(1, 0, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
      mainPanel.add(userNameField, gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(0, 1, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
      mainPanel.add(createLabel("Password:", Color.white), gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(1, 1, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
      mainPanel.add(passwordField, gbc);
      gbc = getGbc(0, 2, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, 2, 1);
      mainPanel.add(btnPanel, gbc);

      mainPanel.setOpaque(false);
      add(mainPanel);
   }

   private JLabel createLabel(String text, Color color) {
      JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
      label.setForeground(color);
      return label;
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (backgrndImage != null) {
         g.drawImage(backgrndImage, 0, 0, this);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet() || backgrndImage == null) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      int imgW = backgrndImage.getWidth();
      int imgH = backgrndImage.getHeight();
      return new Dimension(imgW, imgH);
   }

   public static GridBagConstraints getGbc(int x, int y, int fill) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(I_GAP, I_GAP, I_GAP, I_GAP);
      gbc.fill = fill;

      return gbc;
   }

   public static GridBagConstraints getGbc(int x, int y, int fill, int width,
         int height) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = getGbc(x, y, fill);
      gbc.gridwidth = width;
      gbc.gridheight = height;

      return gbc;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() throws IOException {
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");

      final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "User Sign-In", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
      URL imgUrl = new URL(BKG_IMG_PATH);
      BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
      final DialogExample dlgExample = new DialogExample(img);
      dialog.add(dlgExample);
      dialog.pack();

      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Please Press Me!") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dialog.setVisible(true);
         }
      }));
      mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 650));

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            try {
               createAndShowGui();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Im going to try to do it right away. I'll post here the code or let you know if I have problems with it. To be honest this is the first time I write a GUI program. Anyway an important thing of my program is that it should be always on top and without the menu bar with the close, minimize and maximize buttons. Can I do that as you said? thank you

Comment: I am really trying to do it but I don't know how to start... :( Can you write a small piece of code that I can use as a base? I will accept the response as valid just with that and I will fight with the code to get it work. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi. I have it working but I cant move the JpasswordField to a random X,Y position. HOw can I do that?? Thank you

Comment: @RyanFold: that's a completely different issue, and I invite you to ask a new question on this site regarding it, but the short and **wrong** answer is to set the JPanel's layout to `null` and to set the absolute position of components with `setBounds(...)`. Why this is wrong is because GUI's that use absolute positioning will look terrible on all OS platforms other than the original. Also they are terribly difficult to maintain and enhance. The correct answer is to learn how to use and then use the layout managers.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give one example (amongst many other possibilities), here is a small snippet that shows how to handle this.

Btw, when you call `f.pack(); f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`, then this call is useless: `f.setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width-5, screenSize.height-100);`

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BasicSwingTest2 {

    private JFrame frame;

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        askForPassword();
    }

    private void askForPassword() {
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        BufferedImage myPicture = null;
        try {
            myPicture = ImageIO
                    .read(new URL("http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/blue_abstract_background_310971.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Image dimg = myPicture.getScaledInstance(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width * 2 / 3, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                .getScreenSize().height * 2 / 3, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dimg));
        picLabel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(25);
        password.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Password is " + new String(password.getPassword()));
                dialog.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        picLabel.add(password);

        dialog.add(picLabel);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter your password");
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new BasicSwingTest2().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I like your solution but it shows the menu bar (with the close, minimize and maximize button). Even if I try to do ´frame.setUndecorated(true);´  it does not work. Can you just modify it so it does not show any of that and it appears maximize to the screen resolution? I'll mark the answer as correct because the rest works pretty good. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @RyanFold JDialog don't have min/max buttons. JFrame do. The JDialog is made unresizable anyaway. As to make it take the entire screen size, just remove the `* 2 /3` from the scaling of the image and that should do it.

Comment: If I change that it does not maximize :(